# Why am I not able to access a child method in from an parent object in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm a newbie in Java and playing around in order to try to understand polymorphism I write this code, but gives me the error "Cannot find a.method2()". Here's the code:

```
class A {
  public void method() {
     System.out.println("parent method");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public void method() {
     System.out.println("child method");
  }

  public void method2() {
     System.out.println("child's method 2");
  }
}

public class Main {
  public void main(String[] args) {
   A a = new B();
   a.method2();
 } 
}
```

I'd be thankful if you help me understand.

Comment: Because you've declared it as an `A`. Every `B` is an `A`, but not every `A` is a `B` (and you've specifically called it an `A`) -- `B b = new B();`

Comment: shouldn't that be `a.method2();` in `main`?  I get a syntax error, there is no `b` in `main`.  BTW, you can get to the `.method2` of `a` by casting it to `B`: `((B)a).method2();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the code below will help you understand polymorphism. The trick here is on line 6 where we call `reallyB.method()`. Both our objects' declared type is **A**, yet when we call `reallyA.method()` we get A's behaviour, and when we call `reallyB.method()` we get B's behaviour. This is because B overrides A's implementation of `method`. That's all polymorphism is. Honest. It's not that magical.

If you want to call `method2()` on `reallyB`, you have to **cast** it to a B first (line 7). If you haven't learnt about casting yet, I guarantee it's going to come up in your next lesson / lecture / etc, because it goes hand-in-hand with this topic.

By the way, I recommend calling your classes and functions something other than "method" or "A", "B", "C", etc. It makes reasoning about the behaviour more confusing than it needs to be. Even silly class names like "Dog" or "Cat", and methods like "eat" or "makeSound" are easier to talk about.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A reallyA = new A();
    A reallyB = new B();
    reallyA.method(); // A's implementation
    reallyB.method(); //  B's implementation
    ((B) reallyB).method2(); // B's other method
  }
}

class A {
  public void method() {
    System.out.println("A's implementation");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  @Override
  public void method() {
    System.out.println("B's implementation");
  }

  public void method2() {
    System.out.println("B's other method");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things. Firstly, you never declared a variable `b`, so calling `b.method2()` wouldn’t work. Also, even thought really `a` is assigned an object of `B`, its declared type is of `A`, and therefore can only use methods of type `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access methods in sub class type using parent class reference type.

```
A a = new B();
a.method2();  //error
```

To make it work you need to use type cast:

```
A a = new B();
((B)a).method2();  //works
```